# Prove that a function f is continuous (2)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:$$

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if $x\neq0$} \\
 0 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$

Is the function $f$ continuous in $x=0$?

1) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^-} \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

with the sequence: $x_n=-\frac{1}{n}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}-\frac{1}{n}= 0^-$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos(-n)$

which doesn't exist.

2) $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

 
with the sequence: $x_n=-\frac{1}{n}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}-\frac{1}{n}= 0^+$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos(-n)$

which doesn't exist.

$f$ is not continuous in $x=0$ because after (1) & (2) the both one-side limits for $0$ don't exist.

Is this sufficient to answer the question?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it sufficies to show that *one* of the limits doesn't exist. For example, if you replaced $x \neq 0$ with $x > 0$ and $x = 0$ with $x \leq 0$ in the definition of $f$, it still wouldn't be continuous at $0$.

Comment: Why, when your problem is *whether* $f$ is continuous, does your subject ask us to prove that it *is* continuous?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos n$ doesn't exist? Better to use $x_n=\frac{1}{\pi n}$. Also, your example for $x\to 0^+$ should have positive $x_n$, but you still have chosen negative $x_n$.

Comment: Also, note, after setting $x_n$ values, you write it as $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$, not $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x_n)$ - that doesn't make sense notationally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to use a sequence $x_n$ is correct, but you should go in a different way.

If you find two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$, both converging to $0$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n),$$
then you will have proved (ab absudro) that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Try for example with $x_n=\frac1{2\pi n}$ and $y_n=\frac1{2\pi n+\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $f(x)$ to be continuous at $a$, there must be some number $L$ that satisfies three properties:

1. $\lim_{x\to a+} f(x)=L$
2. $\lim_{x\to a-} f(x)=L$
3. $f(a)=L$

You have shown that both 1 and 2 fail, so you have two proofs that $f$ isn't continuous at 0.